# Attempting to deploy flask site to ubuntu server, ip address not loading

Tags: server, apache2, flask

I have built a flask application on my ubuntu desktop, within virtual environment.

However now I am attempting to upload it to a live ubuntu server 16.04.

I have installed all the dependencies and my enable site apache file looks like this;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName xx.xxx.xxx.xxx

                WSGIDaemonProcess /var/www/WebScraper/WebScraper user='user' group='group' threads=5
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/WebScraper/webscraper.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/WebScraper/WebScraper/>
                        WSGIProcessGroup WebScraper
                        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                        Order deny,allow
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>



</VirtualHost>
```

The x are my ip address for my server and I have replaced, the user and group with my user and group names.

My wsgi looks like this;

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/WebScraper/')


from WebScraper import app as application
```

But each time I type my ip address into the search bar, it returns this took too long

UPDATE

After reading the part at the bottom of docs [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/) I have added the following to my `wsgi` file

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
activate_this = '/var/www/WebScraper/WebScraper/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
        exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/WebScraper/')


from WebScraper import app as application
```

UPDATE 2

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1417/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1446/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5902/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1446/sshd
```

UPDATE 3

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Mar 28 16:26:50.943638 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 5902] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Tue Mar 28 16:26:50.943644 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 5902] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Tue Mar 28 16:26:50.943835 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5902] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 28 16:26:50.943844 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5902] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Is there a firewall?

Comment: no, no firewall

Comment: It sounds like apache isn't running, you should at least get an error. What do you get from the following commands: sudo netstat -lptn    and sudo service apache2 status

Comment: @wildintellect Above is the output. I ran `sudo service apache2 status` and got the green light it is running, so not sure what the problem is

Comment: check the apache logs in /var/log/apache2/ to see if there's an error message

Comment: @wildintellect Update 3 shows the results on the error log from an hour ago. However now the page just doesn't stop loading, normally is loads `this took too long page` but this time it didn't load anything